# How do I connect to a local Android Server from a Chromecast?

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, server, chromecast

What I am trying to do is start a local server on my Android Device and from a Chromecast connect to the Android Server so that I can send image data from the android to a Chromecast.

What I've done so far is set up a ServerSocket on the Android that is binded to the 127.0.0.1 and then send the localhost information (port number) in a message to the chromecast which tells it the serversocket is ready to accept connections and instructs the Chromecast to connect to the server. But I have no idea how I should be connecting to it. I've tried using WebSockets to connect to the ServerSocket but I'm getting

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9147/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've changed the port number, tried both "ws" and "wss" and I've tried searching for the answer but everything I've come across has been "how to connect android to a server" or "how to connect an Android server to an Android client" so I appologize if this is a repost.

What I was planning on doing is using Base64 image encoding to send a String with the image data to the chromecast and then set the image src to that. I obviously not want to do this using Cast.CastAPI.sendMessage().

To be clear, I am looking for a way to connect to an Android server using JavaScript.

The Android code runs fine, the Chromecast gets the message but when it tries to connect it fails.

Android Code:

```
 Runnable bitmapSender = new Runnable() {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 9147;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket binding attempt");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVERPORT));


            String message = createJsonMessage(MessageType.socket, "wss://localhost:"+ SERVERPORT);

            sendMessage(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Socket thread");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                BitmapExecutorService.execute(commThread);

              }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Javascript:

```
    function connectToSocket(source){
     //Connect to socket

        window.socket = new WebSocket(source);
        socket.onopen = function() {
            socket.send('Hello Android');
        };
        window.socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log('Received a message from the server!', data);
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(event.data)
            if(jsonObj.type == "image"){
                console.log('Image sent :)');
                var source = 'data:image/png;base64,'.concat(jsonObj.data)
                displayEncodedImage(source);
            }
        };
```

Thanks

edit: Update
I was trying to connect through localhost. This didn't work like I thought it would. I still haven't got the image sending working but I now have the handshake. What I needed to do was send the IP Address of the phone. I did so by adding the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission to the manifest and obtaining the IP Address with the following code:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Comment: I suggest to not go low level as Socket but instead just add a small web server to your application and then serve content like usual to your receiver; there are small embedded open source web servers that you can find on github and elsewhere to add to your app, or you can write a simple one since you really don't need much functionality there.

Comment: With an embedded web server could I write files to it/ do you know if there is a significant speed trade off?

Comment: I ask because I'm almost done with the handshake for the connection and would be happy to just finish it here if it could be considered better in terms of memory usage/performance

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "write to it". There is practically no speed tradeoff and works perfectly well.

Comment: What I meant was how would I serve content like usual. Should I use an output stream to write the bitmap files to a location on the web server and then send the chromecast a link to the saved images? Thanks